# Unhandled promise rejection : Error: Callback was already called

Tags: node.js

I have to send multiple user data to one external API, which dose not support bulk insert. so i'm looping it and and calling my node API multiple times but getting error.
[enter image description here][1]

```
  / calling api from service

var testArry =  [
{"name":"name1","id":"1" },
{"name":"name2","id":"2" },
{"name":"name3","id":"3" }
];

myAPIFunction(testArry).then(function (status) {
    console.log("Success: ", status);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR : ", err);
})

// API Function

function myAPIFunction(options) { 
    for (var i in options) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios({
                method: "post",
                url: `https:test/url`, // External API to save data
                data: options[i].data
            }).then(function (err, res) {
                console.log("Success : Promise is resolved");
                Promise.resolve(res.data);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("ERROR : Promise is rejected ");
            })
        });
    } // End of loop
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR : TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\git\PayGo\L1SupportAPI\routes\onboarding\index.js:141:55
    at nextTask (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\git\PayGo\L1SupportAPI\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5310:14)
    at next (C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\git\PayGo\L1SupportAPI\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:5317:9)
    at C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\git\PayGo\L1SupportAPI\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:958:16
    at C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\git\PayGo\L1SupportAPI\routes\onboarding\index.js:98:17
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:1284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Callback was already
 called.
(node:1284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
 that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
ERROR : Promise is rejected
ERROR : Promise is rejected
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning anything from that function, therefore .then does not exist.

Also you dont have to create new promise, calling axios is promise on its own:

```
var testArry =  [
{"name":"name1","id":"1" },
{"name":"name2","id":"2" },
{"name":"name3","id":"3" }
];

myAPIFunction(testArry).then(function (status) {
    console.log("Success: ", status);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR : ", err);
})

// API Function

function myAPIFunction(options) { 
    const promises = [];
    for (var i in options) {
            const promise = axios({
                method: "post",
                url: `https:test/url`,
                data: options[i].data
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log("Success : Promise is resolved");
                return res;
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("ERROR : Promise is rejected ");
            })
        promises.push(promise)
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

I have tried to run it with url set to http://google.com and I received this output:

```
ERROR : Promise is rejected
ERROR : Promise is rejected
ERROR : Promise is rejected
Success:  [ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Which is correct, google.com do not accept POST

Comment: Hi, inside promise all i'm getting undefined in response. And inside axios.then getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: I have updated the code to return only res, not res.data, it should help. Then it really matter on what is returned or not from the http call

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response my issue is resolved. :)